# Code to systematically lock excel sheets, only working on 1 spreadsheet (VB)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm basically trying to lock all but one sheet systematically (password driven) in excel. I've developed the following code, however, it only seems to be locking 1 sheet (Dec) of the many sheets. Any help would be HUGELY appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim strPassWord As String
 strPassWord = "apple"

 Sheets("Jan").Select
 Sheets("Feb").Select
 Sheets("Mar").Select
 Sheets("April").Select
 Sheets("May").Select
 Sheets("June").Select
 Sheets("July").Select
 Sheets("Aug").Select
 Sheets("Sept").Select
 Sheets("Oct").Select
 Sheets("Nov").Select
 Sheets("Dec").Select
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strPassWord, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
 ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim strPassWord As String
 strPassWord = InputBox(Prompt:="Password", _
  Title:="Enter Password", Default:="User Password")

 If strPassWord = "apple" Then

  Sheets("Jan").Select
  Sheets("Feb").Select
  Sheets("Mar").Select
  Sheets("April").Select
  Sheets("May").Select
  Sheets("June").Select
  Sheets("July").Select
  Sheets("Aug").Select
  Sheets("Sept").Select
  Sheets("Oct").Select
  Sheets("Nov").Select
  Sheets("Dec").Select
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=strPassWord
 Else
  MsgBox ("Password Incorrect")
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSheet can't be used this way as far as I know. Per the documentation:

> The active sheet (the sheet on top); a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no sheet is active.

It will only lock the last sheet you select. Instead you would be better off having code like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strPassWord As String

    strPassWord = "apple"

    Call LockSheet(Sheets("Sheet1"))
    Call LockSheet(Sheets("Sheet2"))
    Call LockSheet(Sheets("Sheet3"))

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strPassWord As String
    strPassWord = InputBox(Prompt:="Password", _
                            Title:="Enter Password", Default:="User Password")

    If strPassWord = "apple" Then
        Call UnlockSheet(Sheets("Sheet1"), strPassWord)
        Call UnlockSheet(Sheets("Sheet2"), strPassWord)
        Call UnlockSheet(Sheets("Sheet3"), strPassWord)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Password Incorrect")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub LockSheet(sheet As Worksheet)
    sheet.Protect password:=strPassWord, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    sheet.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
End Sub

Private Sub UnlockSheet(sheet As Worksheet, strPassWord As String)
    sheet.Unprotect password:=strPassWord
End Sub
```

Comment: You are the MAN! worked perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a TON!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing code to do this when it is already built into Excel (See "Protect Sheet")? Re-inventing the wheel is generally not a good idea, doubly so for security, triply so when you are hard coding the password in the code which would easily be discovered.

To answer your core question however. ActiveSheet only refers to the sheet on top, not every one that you call select on.

Comment: because the user(s) would have to remember to re-protect the sheets etc... after unlocking them. It's likely that they will have to edit each of the sheets, that means unlocking all of them, and then re-protecting all of them individually, a real pain.

Comment: If it automatically unprotects the sheets when you open the file, then what is the point of protecting it at all?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to select the sheet then password protect it.  The select function changes the ActiveSheet.  It doesn't add to the selection.  This would best be accomplished by moving the lock code to a function, then calling the function after selecting each sheet.

Unlocking the sheet would need a similar tweak.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strPassWord As String
    strPassWord = "apple"

    Sheets("Jan").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("Feb").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("Mar").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("April").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("May").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("June").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("July").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("Aug").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("Sept").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("Oct").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("Nov").Select
    Call LockSheet
    Sheets("Dec").Select
    Call LockSheet

End Sub

Private Sub LockSheet

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strPassWord, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ActiveSheet.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
End Sub
```